# When using `TextVectorization` to tokenize strings, the input rank must be 1 or the last shape dimension must be 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp

I'm traing neural network model to text summarization. i'm using [this](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/praveengovi/emotions-dataset-for-nlp) dataset for model training. after load the train model this issues show up.

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'text_vectorization_1' (type TextVectorization).
    
    When using `TextVectorization` to tokenize strings, the input rank must be 1 or the last shape dimension must be 1. Received: inputs.shape=(None, 7) with rank=2
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'text_vectorization_1' (type TextVectorization):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 7), dtype=string)
```

This is my code so far

```
text_vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=12000,
    output_mode='int',
    output_sequence_length=15
)

text_vectorizer.adapt(train_sentences)

embedding_2 = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
    input_dim=len(text_vectorizer.get_vocabulary()),
    output_dim=128,
    embeddings_initializer='uniform',
    input_length=15,
    name='embedding_2'
) 

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype='string')

x = text_vectorizer(inputs)
x = embedding_2(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64)(x)

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')(x)

model_2 = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name='model_2_simple_lstm')

model_2.compile(
    optimizer='Adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model_2_history = model_2.fit(
    train_sentences,
    train_labels,
    epochs=5,
    validation_data=(val_sentences, val_labels)
)

model_2.save('sentiment_model_LTSM', save_format='tf')
```

This is the summarization code block using save model

```
 Load and tokenize the text
def preprocess_text(text):
    sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
    return sentences


# Load the trained RNN model
def load_model():
    # Assuming you have already trained and saved your RNN model
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/sentiment_model101')
    #model = keras.models.load_model('/content/sentiment_model.h5')
    return model


# Perform sentiment analysis using the loaded RNN model
def perform_sentiment_analysis(sentences, model):
    tokenizer = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
    sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences)
    max_sequence_length = max([len(seq) for seq in sequences])
    padded_sequences = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=max_sequence_length)

    sentiment_scores = model.predict(padded_sequences)

    return sentiment_scores


# Map sentiment scores to emotions
def map_to_emotion(sentiment_scores):
    max_score = np.max(sentiment_scores)
    if max_score >= 0.5:
        return 'joyful'
    elif max_score <= -0.5:
        return 'angry'
    elif max_score <= -0.2:
        return 'sad'
    else:
        return 'neutral'


# Generate the text summary based on emotions
def generate_summary(text):
    sentences = preprocess_text(text)

    model = load_model()

    sentiment_scores = perform_sentiment_analysis(sentences, model)

    emotion_trigger = map_to_emotion(sentiment_scores)

    max_score = np.max(sentiment_scores)
    max_sentence = sentences[np.argmax(sentiment_scores)]

    summary = f"The text evokes a {emotion_trigger} emotion. The key sentence is: '{max_sentence}'"

    return summary
```

Comment: Try to change `inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype='string')` into `inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1), dtype='string')`. The difference is in `(1,)`=>`(1)`. It effect input shape.

Comment: Thank You Marko for answering. But it didn't sloved the isse. It remains the same